# Pass user input from HTML into VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript

I am trying to create a simple user interface in HTML that asks the user to enter an integer for a transfer volume. I want to use that input as a variable in a VBScript, but I keep getting a display input error. For example, if the user enters 50, I want the message box to display 50.

```
<html>
<form>
<label for="transfer_vol">Transfer Volume:</label>
<input type="number" name="transfer_vol" id=transfer_vol min="0" 
max="200" size="8">
</form>

<script language="vbscript" type="text/Vbscript">
<!--
Function displayValue(transfer_vol)
Msgbox(transfer_vol)
End Function
//-->
</script>

<input type = "button" onclick = "displayInput(transfer_vol)" value = "Confirm Parameters" />
</html>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use VBScript for this. No modern browsers, including Microsofts, support it. Use Javascript instead.

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to program a liquid handling robot and afaik the software uses vbscript

Comment: @stan you probably should have mentioned that. I thought the question was about webpages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you using HTA instead of HTML if you want to use vbscript :

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pass user input from HTA into VBScript</title>
 <HTA:APPLICATION
 Application ID = "Input"
 APPLICATIONNAME = "Input"
 BORDER = "Dialog"
 BORDERSTYLE = "Normal"
 />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES">
 <style type="text/css">
  body {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #49403B;
        background: LightBlue;
        }
</style>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/Vbscript">
Function displayValue()
    Set vol = document.getElementbyID("transfer_vol")
    Msgbox(vol.value)
End Function
</script>
</head>     
<body>
<label>Transfer Volume:</label>
<input type="text" name="transfer_vol" id="transfer_vol" max="200" size="8">
<input type="button" onclick="displayValue" value = "Confirm Parameters" />
</boy>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will try that

Comment: It works! Thanks so much! I am trying to program a liquid handling robot for work so you have been very helpful